# Why does my Spring Boot web app not run completely in Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I've been trying to set up a new Spring Boot Web application using the following command:

```
spring init --java-version=1.7 --build=gradle --packaging=war --groupId=me.psychopunch.lab.springboot --artifactId=sample --name=quickstart sample
```

However, when I trying running the generated code using: `gradle bootRun`, I build does not complete, and does not throw error either. I only get:

```
...
2016-01-11 22:44:28.127  INFO 3579 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-11 22:44:28.260  INFO 3579 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-11 22:44:28.266  INFO 3579 --- [           main] com.example.QuickstartApplication        : Started QuickstartApplication in 5.312 seconds (JVM running for 6.091)
> Building 80% > :bootRun
```

The build gets stuck at around 80%. Sometimes it's 83%, 85%, etc. but it won't complete up to 100%. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I get the same symptom loading the Spring Boot 2.0 apps from here:  https://github.com/bijukunjummen/boot2-load-demo

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's actually running that's what the *Started QuickstartApplication in 5.312 seconds (JVM running for 6.091)* indicate.

Ignore the *> Building 80% > :bootRun*. When you terminate the spring process some more cleanup things will run in gradle.

I have a pretty big build process, mine prints *Started...* at 96%. :)

It's perfectly normal.

Comment: It's not working for me though. When I define a controller for example, it redirects me to an error page.

Comment: Maybe your Application have an error somewhere then? What does it say? It's a 404? Where do you try to access the app?

Comment: In my case I cannot acces localhost:8080 but can indeed access the "/greeting" endpoint as shown in this startup guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @VicTorious Do you have a controller for "/" or do you have an index.html added as a static resource? If not then you will get a 404 as a result when trying to access "/".

Comment: @LakatosGyula well, I just followed the mentioned Guide - so no, I have neither of these. I actually thought, that in this case I should land at some kind of "default Tomcat page".

Comment: Well, it's a relief that *"it's perfectly normal"*, but at the same time, I disagree with that sentence. I wouldn't call a hanging progress indicator normal.

Comment: @MCEmperor It is not hanging, merely waiting for your app to finish. As a webapp it will only happen once you kill it, but as a command line application, it might finish running in a couple of seconds for example.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Web App can run in Gradle.
It could be that your IDE does not support Spring project.

Regarding SpringBoot Setup, you may follow these steps from my GitHub Project:
https://github.com/worldpeacez0991/SpringBoot_demo1

Give a star to my project if it helps you :)